# Is it possible to train a woman's body at home?

Tags: workout, bulking, personal-training, physique

I am a 19 year old girl. I want to have a lean physique like leanbeefpatty, who is a Tiktok star. I have trained myself for a few months before, but I stopped doing it because of summer heat. My weight is around 110lb and my height is 167cm. Is it possible for me to bulk up?

How can I bulk up at home? I can't go out because my family is a strict type.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the fitness influencer your referring to has an extremely good physique for a female and likely had years of training to attain it, so I would highly recommend not basing your goals off of how she looks and instead just focus on your own personal goals I.e a target bodyweight or a PR goal for a lift.

Secondly, a 'bulk' refers to your diet more than the specifics of your training, in particular, being in a caloric surplus. Eating adequate protein is of course also essential but that's true of a bulking, maintenance or cutting regime.

To find out how many calories you need for a surplus, use any simple online calorie calculator to find your 'maintenance calories' and add on 200-300 calories to create a surplus.
For protein you will need anywhere from 0.5g to 1g of protein per lb of bodyweight. That's a big range but it varies greatly from person to person and depends on how intense your training is, you just need to vary it and see what works for you.